# Cordova dialogs plugin: cannot read property alert

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I have been trying to use the cordova dialogs plugin on a hybrid phone app, on android. It kept returning the same error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined

Therefore I stripped the app down to the bare minimum. In my cordova directory, I have one super simple html file, that starts up the javascript file.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in that script.js file, I have copied and pasted the exact example code from the cordova API and cordova dialogs plugin API.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/

```
  function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }
  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.notification);
  }
  function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
  }

  navigator.notification.alert(
      'You are the winner!',  // message
      alertDismissed,         // callback
      'Game Over',            // title
      'Done'                  // buttonName
  );
```

I then run the app on my android phone in terminal with cordova run, the app builds and launches without issue. But I do not get an alert. When I inspect the app, it again gives me the same uncaught type error.

Does anyone have an idea on why this won't work?

I'm running it on
OSX 10.12.3
Cordova v 6.5.0
Android command line tools installed, with jdk 25.2.5

Also, the plugin is installed in the cordova directory and I can see it in the plugin folder.

Comment: I have found the solution. I had missed you had to import the cordova.js in your html to use the plugin. So I have added  
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
And now it works!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, what cordova.js? The one in node_modules? You can't just import that file, it's expected to be run through node.js